# How would I shorten this few lines of python code?

Tags: python

In python how can I shorten the code below?

```py
if x == 15:
   y = 0
elif x == 14:
   y = 1
elif x == 13:
   y = 2
...
...
...
elif x == 0:
   y = 15
```

Currently the solutions I've gotten are

```
y = 15-x
```

and adding a dictionary.

Comment: Do you mean literally like make it one line or character based?

Comment: something like `y = 15-x if 0<= x <= 15 else None`?

Comment: Why does the code have to be shortened?

Comment: @enke, when x is 14, that would make y 1, not 2 as required.

Comment: If i understand it correctly, you can simply do a `y=15-x`?

Comment: have a dictionary if there is no underlying pattern and return the value (y) for every key(x) ... ```d = {15:0, 14:2, 12:3, ... 0:15} print (d[x])```

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem, can you please provide some context on what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There Is A Pattern Your Code if x = 15 then y = 0 and if x = 14 then y = 1.
If you just subtract x from 15 then you get the value of y.
There is an equation made (if you know about math):

```
x+y = 15
then,
y = 15 -x
```

This Is The Code.

```py
x = #value you use
y = 15 -x
```

Comment: @kid Dictionary solution is also working but it's too long.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice to not use so many `if`/`elif` conditions is to use a `dict`

```
my_dct = {15: 0, 14: 2, 12: 3, 0: 15}
y = my_dct[x]
```

Comment: This code is also too lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
for i in range(16,-1,-1):
   y = i -1
   if y == 0:
      y=15
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
x = 0 # some number

for i in range(15,-1,-1):
    if x == i:
        y = 15 - i
        
print(y)
```